# How to test personal access token using Guzzlehttp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport, guzzle

I'm working on Laravel Passport. I have created a personal access token. Now, I want to test it using guzzlehttp Client. How can i do this.
I'm try this way it's not working.

**`routes/web.php`**

```
Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
     $response = (new GuzzleHttp\Client)->post('http://passportauth.test/oauth/token', [
            'form_params' => [
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                'client_id' => 1, // Laravel Personal Access Client ID
                'client_secret' => 'zeFLAy76pZdCuHuKXjPCEgY0MMhnkADYbIRKzZQz', // Replace with client secret
                'redirect_uri' => 'http://passportauth.test/callback',
                'code' => $request->code,
            ]
        ]);

        session()->put('token', json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true));

        return redirect('/test');
         //return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
    });

 Route::get('/test', function () {
   $response = (new GuzzleHttp\Client)->get('http://passportauth.test/api/test', [
       'headers' => [
           'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.session()->get('token.access_token')
       ]
   ]);

   return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

and my `routes/api.php` .

```
Route::get('/test',function(){
return 'This is an API Endpoints';
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

Comment: I don't think dot-notation works like that for `session()`, shouldn't it be `session()->get("token")->access_token`?

Comment: `'Bearer '.session()->get('token')` this way ??

Comment: `session()->get("token")->access_token`, exactly as I wrote it... You're setting `token` into session, which is an object, so get it with `session()->get("token")` then access the property `access_token` via `->access_token` (or `["access_token"]` if it's an array)

Comment: it's show `"error": "invalid_client",
"message": "Client authentication failed"`

Comment: Do a `dd(session()->get("token"));` in your `test` route and see if it has what you expect in it.

Comment: show `null` result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176590/discussion-between-gabrielle-and-tim-lewis).

Comment: That would be why your authentication is unsuccessful. Somewhere along that line, your `access_token` object isn't be set into session, so you're passing `Bearer ` to your API, which will fail authentication.

Comment: i'm tested `http://passportauth.test/api/test` in `Postman` it's show output but `http://passportauth.test/test` it's show nothing

Comment: I doubt the token you're storing in `session()->put()` is available to subsequent calls from `Postman`.

Comment: @TimLewis can you give me an example how to test it ??. last two days i'm stuck on this problem.

Comment: Don't use `session()`. Return the `access_token` as a `JSON` response in your `/callback` route, then do a call directly to `/api/test` with `Postman` and set `Authorization` header to `Bearer ` + the access token returned in the first call. That's how APIs are usually meant to be called; session-less.